# ClassNotFoundException while using Class.forname

Tags: java, arrays, class, methods

I am writing a generic interpreter. It contains primitive processes (such as method calling, return from method, control statements, etc.), that are run by a translator that reads the source code, written in any language, and activates the primitives. The core of this translator is constructed from a strings array that contains the names of the methods that implemets the processes and dynamic activation of the method.

The following code is used to invoke the method pointed to by the index procIndex. It is based on an example I found, and is the same as other examples:

```
try {
    Class<?> c = Class.forName("FinalTestDecoder");
    Method  commandExe = 
         c.getDeclaredMethod (commandsTable[commandIndex][methodName], (Class<?>[])null);
    commandExe.invoke (commandExe, (Object []) null);
} catch (IllegalAccessException| IllegalArgumentException| 
       InvocationTargetException| EmptyStackException | 
        ClassNotFoundException | NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException  e) { 
  handleErr(cmdMethodNotFound, "Command: "+ commandsTable[commandIndex][programCommand]); 
} finally {
   found = true; 
}   // Cause the loop to terminate
```

The handleErr method is handling the error condition and gets decimal error code and a string. The error handler can be invoked by any of the exceptions.

The problem is in the line `Class<?> c = Class.forName("FinalTestDecoder");`, that throws the ClassNotFoundException. To overcome this I made two experiments: originally, the invoked methods were in the same class as the invoking code; n the second I created an embedde class that contained the invoked methods. The result was the same.

Well, I spent hours on this issue and ran out of ideas. any help will be thankfully welcomed

Comment: are you using fully qualified class name for FinalTestDecoder?

Answer (score 7):

You must use the full qualified class name, which is required for the method [forName](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName%28java.lang.String%29). Something like this:-

```
Class.forName("com.test.class.file.diretory.FinalTestDecoder");
```

Comment: Dear RJ, Thank you very much - this realy solved the issue of that line. However, it brought me to the next line, where the method is declared. This line invokes NoSuchMethodException. I tried to add the class name before (which is, of course, irrelevant) and replaced the vector reference with the method name. Nothing. can you please help again?

Comment: Dear AmitG and RJ, thank you for the answers. This indeed solved the problem with that line. However, I have now an issue with the next line, that declares the method by its name, and generates NoSuchMethodException. I replaced the array reference with the method name, wit no change. Can you please halp me again?

Comment: So, is the method you are looking for inherited or declared for the class in question. getDeclaredMethod won't return inherited methods.

Comment: The method is declared in this class and not inherited